# Pickle psycopg2 NumericRange

Tags: python, postgresql, pickle, numeric-ranges

I'm trying to write some data to a cache of which some has been retrieved from a postgres db using psycopg2 and sqlalchemy. Some of them are `NumericRange` instances. Unfortunately, when I try to pickle the objects before writing them to the Redis cache, they raise an exception.

```
lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 77, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError("a class that defines __slots__ without "
TypeError: a class that defines __slots__ without defining __getstate__ cannot be pickled
```

Is it possible to change pickle, so it can deal with `NumericRange` objects? Note `cpickle` is used for the serialization.

Comment: My psychic powers tell me that this is a bug in SQLAlchemy, similar to [this bug in Django](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25501).

Comment: Well, more `psycopg2`, but that awareness doesn't really help me...

Comment: The problem with Django is that they were calling `pickle.dumps(value)` instead of `pickle.dumps(value, -1)`.  You need the latter.  But if this pickling is happening deep inside SQLAlchemy, then you need to talk to the developers of SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Actually, that helps. I just tried `protocol=2` which apparently is for Python 2.x (https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format) and it seems to work. The pickling is happening in a Flask extension which I can override. Thanks.

Comment: An alternative (for future readers who can't alter the pickle protocol) is to register a new type on the psycopg2 connection itself that will convert a numeric range to a child class that can be pickled.  See http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#database-types-casting-functions

Comment: @donkopotamus Interesting, thanks for the comment.